# missing include files during gcc compilation of c program in CentOS

Tags: c, linux, gcc, curl, centos

I am getting the following errors about missing include libraries when I try to use `gcc` to compile a c program called `some.c` on a CentOS 7 server as shown below.  **How can I resolve these errors so that the program compiles properly?**

```
[user@domain ~]$ gcc -fPIC -lcurl -c some.c
some.c:10:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
#include <curl/curl.h>
compilation terminated.
```

When I comment out `#include <curl/curl.h>` and try again, I get:

```
[user@domain ~]$ gcc -fPIC -lcurl -c some.c
some.c:11:31: fatal error: security/pam_appl.h: No such file or directory
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
compilation terminated.
```

I image I would get another error for `#include <security/pam_modules.h>` if I kept commenting out the include directives, because the list of includes as the top of `some.c` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
```

In Java, the imports are handled by the jvm/jdk, so you don't have to worry about this kind of thing.  Or you use maven if it is not a core library.  Or you place all the jar dependencies in a folder that you mark as the classpath.  Is there some easy solution to this c problem like `yum install clibs`?  Or do I have to manually move libraries to some directory?  **How can I resolve these compilation errors so that `gcc` can successfully compile the `some.c` program?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install curl and pam development packages:

```
sudo yum install curl-devel
sudo yum install pam-devel
```

Comment: Does the command succeeds to install curl-devel? If yes do you still get the same error `curl/curl.h: No such file or directory`?

Comment: Your suggestion eliminated the `curl/curl.h` error, but the two `pam` errors still remain, so the code cannot compile.

Comment: Thank you and +1.  That seemed to do it.